# How to mark windows or set windows titles in Gnome3 via script

Tags: window, gnome3, gtk, title-bar

I'm inspecting different versions of a GTK application, binary with no source code, and doing frequent ALT-Back-Quotes for visual inspection. Every now and then I would lose track of versions because they all look the same.

I'm looking for a way to mark the windows or perhaps add the version to the title bar text. Is there a simple trick to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tool called [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), which can be used for the purpose of this question like so:

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --name 'My super app.*' set_window --name "VERSION1"
```